# What is the difference between gksu and sudo?

Tags: sudo

I presume this applies to any Gnome desktop. What is the difference between these two commands? According to the [Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) and [questions that reference it](https://askubuntu.com/q/11825/24342), the former also sets the `$HOME` environment variable and copy the .Xauthority variable to temporary location, but are those the only differences for all systems running Gnome, or do they only apply to Ubuntu?

Comment: Between gksu and sudo? Or between gksu and gksudo?

Comment: @Gilles I thought `gksudo` just linked to `gksu`, at least on [Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/a/21040/24342).

Comment: @RicardoAltamirano that doesn't mean anything. It can still function differently

Comment: @warl0ck Can `gksudo` function differently on a system (like Ubuntu) where it's nothing more than symlink to `gksu`? (It's a serious question. I don't know enough about Linux to know if it makes a difference).

Comment: @RicardoAltamirano by checking the name of the soft link, if it's `gksudo`, act like gksudo; if it's `gksu` act like `gksu`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After searching at greater length and finding [a](http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=8468) [few](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/graphicalsudo) [other](https://askubuntu.com/a/11831/24342) [sources](http://www.answeredubuntu.com/11825/is_the_difference_between_sudo_and_gksu_the_same_as_the_difference_between_sudo_i_and_sudo_s), I think it's safe to say that `gksu` is nothing more than a `wrapper` around `sudo` in most cases. [This source](http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?pid=75644#p75644) states that since `gksu` displays a password dialog, it's used for graphical applications (as we already know) because it can be used outside a terminal emulator. Otherwise, running `sudo <cmd>` from a launcher wouldn't work because the user wouldn't be prompted for a password.

Answer (score 1):

I remember I couldn't run some X applications with `sudo`, but was able to run them with `gksudo` or `kdesudo`.